# Spring Web Flow LocalValidatorFactoryBean (JSR-349) does not work how is expected

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-3, spring-webflow-2, spring-4

I am working with Spring 4.0.7 and Spring Web Flow 2.4.0

I have the following (I am working with `JSR 349`):

For an entity:

```
@Min(value=1, message="{person.age.min}",groups={PersonRegistrationCheck.class})
@Max(value=115, message="{person.age.max}",groups={PersonRegistrationCheck.class})
@NotNull(message="{field.null}",groups={PersonRegistrationCheck.class})
@Column(name="age", nullable=false, length=3)
@XmlElement
public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

In the `ValidationMessages.properties` file

```
person.age.max = Invalid data '${validatedValue}', the maximum value allowed is {value}
person.age.min = Invalid data '${validatedValue}', the minimum value allowed is {value}
```

In some `@Configuration`

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource){

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);

    MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator msrbl = new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(messageSource); 
    ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator rbmi = new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(msrbl);
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(rbmi);

    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

Through Spring MVC it works perfectly fine:

```
<tr>
    <td><spring:message code="person.form.age"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="age" size="40"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
```

If I put an invalid value how 500 I get

> Invalid data 500, the maximum value allowed is 115

I can see the invalid data and the maximum value allowed.

Until here all is OK..

**Note**: is **not** necessary do a special injection about `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` for `Spring MVC`

The problem is with Spring Web Flow.

**Note**: is **necessary** do a special injection about `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` for `Spring Web Flow`

Here its configuration:

```
@Autowired
private LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean;

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
            .setConversionService(conversionService())              
            .setValidator(localValidatorFactoryBean)
            .setDevelopmentMode(true)   
            .build();
}
```

Above is practically **almost** the same according with [spring-webflow-samples
/ WebFlowConfig](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/blob/master/booking-mvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/webflow/samples/booking/config/WebFlowConfig.java)

In the flow definition

```
<view-state id="start" 
        view="person.flow.form.register" 
        model="person"
        validation-hints="'com.manuel.jordan...PersonRegistrationCheck'"  >
    <transition on="submit" to="address" bind="true" validate="true" >
        <evaluate expression="personAction.savePerson(flowRequestContext)" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" to="end" bind="false" validate="false"/>
</view-state>
```

Again in the .jsp file

```
<tr>
    <td><spring:message code="person.form.age"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="age" size="40"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
```

**Note**: It is other or new .jsp file, it to work for Spring Web Flow. 
          Therefore one to work through `Spring MVC` and other for `SWF`. 
          It for testing purposes

Ok the problem:

Again If I put an invalid value how 500 I get

> Invalid data $validatedValue, the maximum value allowed is value

Observe: We **can't** see, the invalid data (remains with $validatedValue) and `value` remains how static.

Therefore:

- `Spring MVC` shows: `Invalid data 500, the maximum value allowed is 115`
- `SWF` shows:  `Invalid data $validatedValue, the maximum value allowed is value`

Note: Even If use the following, all go wrong yet.

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource){

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);

    //MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator msrbl = new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(messageSource); 
    //ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator rbmi = new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(msrbl);
    //localValidatorFactoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(rbmi);

    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

What is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [booking-mvc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/booking-mvc) sample I could confirm all works as expected. I tried both ValidationMessages.properties with default LocalValidatorFactoryBean (i.e. no custom interpolator, just relying on Hibernate validator) as well as "/WEB-INF/messages.properties" with a custom ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator pointing to the ResourceBundleMessageSource.

Several notes on the above:

- setValidationMessageSource and setMessageInterpolator on LocalValidatorFactoryBean are mutually exclusive. The javadoc clearly states that.
- ValidationMessages.properties is the default (JSR-303) bean validation mechanism. Once you set a custom MessageInterpolator, ValidationMessages.properties is no longer used.
- Support for ${validatedValue} seems to be something that's available with Hibernate validator version 5+, i.e. it's not available in 4.3.
- in Web Flow we also look at messages.properties in the flow directory. Need to make sure there aren't any error codes that are overriding the JSR-303 resolved violation messages.

With those in mind everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks Rossen. Let me test it, this weekend.